# How can I remove leading zeroes and convert an alphabet letter to a number?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df column with values like this: 000000000056H, 000000000193E. I need to remove the leading zeroes and change the last letter to the corresponding number, e.g. a = 1, e = 5 etc. The values should be 568 and 1935 in these examples.

I have tried to convert to int but this doesn't work, probably because of the end character.

I tried .strip("0") but I got an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'

Can anyone suggest any help on this? I am new to python so this is beyond my very limited knowledge!

Tia

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
import string
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['0000000056H', '00000000193E'])
repdict = {v:str(k) for k, v in dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, start=1)).items()}
s.str.strip('0').replace(repdict, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0     568
1    1935
dtype: object
```

Comment: that looks great, how would you apply that to a column?

Comment: Instead of s use df['colname'].

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me - thanks very much

import string
import pandas as pd

repdict = {v:str(k) for k, v in dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, start=1)).items()}
s.str.strip('0').replace(repdict, regex=True)

Comment: @instead of  posting this here you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the appropriate solution.  Please delete this answer.